# react-native-router-flux refreshing component with Replace, Reset, and Refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, refresh, react-native-router-flux

So I've been using ignite CLI which includes react-native-router-flux.

My question is, I'm having a data from props which will be uploaded to the database when the user press 'apply' here's the code

`<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.onApply.bind(this)}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Apply</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>`

```
async onApply(){

var token = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY)
var url = "http://purwadhikaconnect.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com/api/applicants"
var jobId = this.props.jobData.Id
console.log('int?', jobId);
var config = {
  method: "POST",
  headers:{
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    'Accept' : 'application/json',
    "Authorization" : 'Bearer ' + token
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    JobId : parseInt(jobId)
  })
}

return fetch(url, config).then((response) => response.json())
.then(this.setState({
  isApplied: true,
})).then((response) =>{Alert.alert('Job Applied Successfully')})
.then(this.setState({currentApplicant: this.state.currentApplicant + 1})) //trying to manipulate the value
.then(NavigationActions.Jobs({type: 'reset'}))
.catch((exception) => {Alert.alert('You have applied for this job!')})
```

}

now the data is successfully uploaded but it wont automatically refresh. I've been using component update lifecycle such as `shouldComponentUpdate()`
and you could see that my Action type there is `reset`. Now the issue with using `Actionconst.replace` is that my menu button will be replaced with back button. And if I use
`ActionConst.refresh()` it wont refresh as well. Please help me I've been dealing with this for months and I've tried almost everything to solve it but to no avail and its getting frustrating...;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're passing setStates as an argument of your .then's, try changing it to this:

```
.then((response) => this.setState({ isApplied: true }))
```

Comment: Well thanks mate you've just give me a new insight. I can modify my web controller to include the modified data inside the `(response)` but is it a good practice or is there a better solution?

Comment: I don't think there is a standard practice, but I like to return the data on post requests.